# SQLite create table error in constructor in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm try to create a new `database` and `table` in my `constructor class`, but I find in this line error:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST tblApp ( _ID INTEGER PRIMARY kEY AUTOINCREMENT UNION, Title TEXT )",null);
```

and crashed my app.

This is my class:

```
package ir.rezvania.modirbash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class db {
    Context ctx;
    Cursor crs;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    public db(Context ctx){
       this.ctx=ctx;
        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase("`dbApp`", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST `tblApp` ( _ID Integer Primary key autoincrement union, Title Text )",null);
    }
    public void Insert(String FILDS,String VALUES){
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO `tblApp` ("+FILDS+")VALUES("+VALUES+");");
    }
    public void Update(String ID,String COLUMN,String VALUE){
        db.execSQL("UPDATE `tblAPP` SET"+COLUMN+"="+VALUE+"WHERE _ID="+ID+";");
    }
    public void Delete(String ID){
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM `tblApp` WHERE _ID="+ID+";");
    }
    public Cursor Show(){
        crs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM `tblApp`",null);
        return crs;
    }

    public void finalize(){
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: follow https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: post your error log

Comment: You have **a lot** of errors, not only in the table creation command. EVERY command and the query is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your table creation fails, because you're using the wrong wording. It's `IF NOT EXISTS` you need to use. For simplicity you should use caps for all keys. Also you don't need to use `` ` `` since `tblApp` is not a keyword, `union` doesn't make any sense where you put it and [`AUTOINCREMENT` is not needed](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblApp (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Title TEXT)", null);
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQLite a column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement. There is no autoincrement keyword in SQLite, that is why you are getting an error.
You can find out more on [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).

Comment: There's an `AUTOINCREMENT` in SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html check this link also

Comment: But still it's not an error to put the key somewhere. It's just not necessary or efficient.